# Django: Handling discount codes

Tags: django

I am currently building a Django application where visitors can buy an online course. I now want to implement the possibility to provide discount codes. As these discount codes should be limited by quantity I now have the following implementation idea:

1. Guest visits www.page.com?discount=TEST
2. The model `discount` contains the fields `discount_codes` & `max qty`. I will check here, if the code exists. Also, I have to count all entries in my order model that used the discount code TEST. My order model contains the `foreign_key` field 'redeemed_discounts').
3. As soon the user clicks on Pay (via Stripe) I'll once again count all the orders in my order model which contain 'TEST' to make sure, the 'max_qty' is not reached meanwhile.
4. Now I can charge the visitor.

Would you consider this as good implemented or do you see any problems with the way I am planning to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using max_qty why don't you use something like use_left and max_use
so whenever someone uses that code you can reduce the count accordingly and when count hits zero you can stop using that with this approach you don't have to scan order table every time to see if the coupon code is still available.

Comment: btw that's how we implemented coupon in my past startup.

Comment: I like the approach. I didn't use it because I thought it could be 'risky' in case many people use the coupon at the same time. Couldn't it happen, that the count goes wrong?

Let's say User 1 & User 2 order at the same time.

User 1: Check use_left > 10 - 1 = 9. New use left > 9
User 2: Check use_left > 10 - 1 = 9. New use left > 9

I miss to count User 1 if that process happens at the same time. Or do you not see that risk?

Comment: no, we did and this is where transactions come in handy for ref you can look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: Aha that's very interesting. So just that I understood it correctly. In the view where I execute the calculation use_left - 1, I write `@transaction.atomic`. That way I tell Django: If there is already a transaction running, it has to wait till the previous one is finished. Did I understand it correct?

Comment: yeah pretty much